# Interpolation using the selected config group option in Hydra

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

I am using hydra composition with the following structure:

```py
├── configs
    │   ├── config.yaml
    │   ├── data
    │   │   ├── dataset_01.yaml
    │   │   └── dataset_02.yaml
    │   └── model
    │       ├── bert.yaml
    │       └── gpt.yaml
```

- config.yaml

```py
defaults:
  - model: bert
  - data: dataset_01

...
```

- data/dataset_01.yaml

```py
# @package _group_

name: "dataset_01"

train:
  path: "../resources/datasets/dataset_01/train.jsonl"
  num_samples: 1257391

test:
  path: "../resources/datasets/dataset_01/test.jsonl"
  num_samples: 71892

val:
  path: "../resources/datasets/dataset_01/val.jsonl"
  num_samples: 73805
```

- model/bert.yaml

```py
# @package _group_

name: "bert"

encoder: "source.encoder.BertEncoder.BertEncoder"

encoder_hparams:
  architecture: "bert-base-uncased"

lr: 1e-7

tokenizer:
  architecture: "bert-base-uncased"

predictions:
  path: "../resources/predictions/bert_predictions.pt"
```

- entry point

```py
@hydra.main(config_path="configs/", config_name="config.yaml")
def perform_tasks(hparams):

    model = MyModel(hparams.model)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    perform_tasks()
```

In the context of `hparams.model`, there is no way for OmegaConf to interpolate the key `data.name` since it is not in scope.
So, it would be great if there was an approach to causes the interpolation at the beginning of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OmegaConf interpolation is absolute and is operating on the final config.

Try this:
With Hydra 1.1 or newer you can use [`hydra.runtime.choices`](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/configure_hydra/intro/#hydraruntime) which is a dictionary containing the config groups you have selected.

You will be able to interpolate without adding the name field using `hydra:runtime.choices.GROUP_NAME`:

```yaml
predictions:
  path: "dir/bert_${hydra:runtime.choices.GROUP_NAME}_pred.pt"
```

Comment: Hello, actually I did not want to interpolate the name of the model (which is in the same file `model/bert.yaml`). Instead, I would like to interpolate the name of the data that is in an external file (`data/dataset_01.yaml`)

Comment: The question sure is confusing. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already tried this approach, but without success. When print the result config (`print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(config))`) results in: `path: ../resources/predictions/bert_${data.name}_predictions.pt`

Comment: OmegaConf.to_yaml() does not resolve interpolations by default. you can pass resolve=True to do that.
Note that when you are accessing a field the interpolation is resolved.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you go over the OmegaConf docs or slides (linked from the project README).

Comment: Using `print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(hparams, resolve=True))` prints the desired result. However, when using directly `hparams.model.predictions` still giving: `../resources/predictions/bert_${data.name}_predictions.pt`

Comment: Please file a bug with a minimal repro. I am having a hard time believing this.

Comment: This is happing because only part of the configuration is passed to instantiate the model (`model/bert.yaml`). And in this context, there is no way for `OmegaConf` to interpolate the key `data.name` since it is not in scope. So, is there an approach to causes the interpolation at the beginning of the application?

Comment: Your analysis is incorrect. StackOverflow is not a good support channel. Please file an issue with a minimal working example against Hydra to ask your question.

Comment: Please try to follow the advice here when asking the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @CelsoFrança, I believe the answer I provided is correct (given your discovery that the issue was related to PyTorch Lightning). Do you mind accepting the answer?