# Hydra access config filename from group

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I want to access in my python code the name of the Hydra config file that I have choosen from the command line.

Let's consider this basic project architecture from the Hydra documentation:

```
├── conf
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── mysql.yaml
│   │   └── postgresql.yaml
└── my_app.py
```

Then, let's say I run `python my_app.py db=postgresql` to choose `postgresql` from the group `db`.
Then, in my python code, I will be able to access what is **inside** `config.db`, but how to access the `db` name itself? In other words, how to get `postgresql` from `config`?

I don't want to parse the command line arguments (even though this is very easy), but I am looking for a clean and easy way to do it with the Hydra config directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65552653/interpolation-using-the-selected-config-group-option-in-hydra), this is possible since Hydra 1.1 with: `${hydra:runtime.choices.db}`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you add a name field to each of the configs.

```yaml
# mysql.yaml
name: mysql
host: localhost
port: 3306
```

Comment: So there is no way to avoid repeating the filename in this « name field »?

Comment: Not that I know.